# vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('languajeID').update('propiedades','stringVal');

Tags: api, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have more than 2 weeks trying to figure out how can I change my setting value from VSCode API but without a result.

It is started getting quite frustrated, because the VSCode API is not greatly documented, and on the internet not of the example I find doesn't work.

**I am creating a VSCode language extension, but what I want to do is from the extension.js change the string value of my language configuration setting to another string value.**

This is the code I am using that is support to work but doesn't: `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('languajeID').update('propiedades','stringVal', true, true);`

Comment: what is the part of `package.json` that defines this configuration setting

Comment: is this the actual code you try? not likely you have named your setting: `propiedades`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution for this problem that I had. I forget to post it.**

So, to change a VSCode configuration property value to another value by using a variable in your extension.js file here is how it should be done:

```
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update("extantionName-property.propertyName", variableName.toString(), vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);
```

> **extantionName-property.propertyName:** It is the name you already gave to your configuration panel when you declared it in your
> package.json file.
>
> **variableName:** It is the name of the variable you declared in your extention.js file, which has the value you want on your property to be
> assigned.

I hope this can help anyone who has the sample concert as I did want I was making my VSCode extension.